# iOS block function called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a block function defined as the below:

```
@property (atomic, assign) bool callInProgress;

//in implementation:    

- (void)synchronize:(void(^)(void(^unlock)()))block {
    if (!_callInProgress) {
        _callInProgress = YES;
        [_tableView setScrollEnabled:false];

        block(^{
            [_tableView setScrollEnabled:true];
            _callInProgress = NO;
        });
    }
}
```

Then when I do:

```
[self synchronize:^(void(^unlock)()) {
}];
```

and I set a break point at that `[self synchronize..]`, the break point gets hit twice no matter what! If I add a body:

```
/*break point on this line*/ [self synchronize:^(void(^unlock)()) {
    NSLog(@"HERE");
    unlock();
}];
```

`HERE` gets printed ONCE but the break point gets hit twice!

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The breakpoint is being hit once when you reach the synchronize call, and once when you enter the callback block.  Both are on the same line.

Comment: Ahahaha! What in the world.. Never thought I'd see the day when coding style catches me off guard. Thanks! I was trying to figure out what was going on for the last 2 hours!